# No upvote comment in app?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was not able to find an upvote button for comments in the mobile app (Android). Am I missing something? I'd appreciate to able to use this feature :) Twice now that I've went back to the web to upvote a very pertinent comment.

I can see the votes count, and there seems to be plenty of space for a upvote button:

[image: Example of comments in the APP]

I'm pretty sure I'm either not seeing the obvious or there is a good reason for a basic feature like that not being implemented, but would love to hear either way.

Comment: Is that the Stack Exchange app or the Stack Overflow one?

Comment: The Stack Exchange app; I was unaware there were two. Will investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you are logged in on the site in question, you just have to tap on the comment you want to upvote, and the upvote button will be on the top right.

[image: screenshot]